# Dynamic Div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to create a unique div and a unique name for each submit button -I'm new to jQuery-
please help me.

```
$(document).ready( function() {  
    done();
});

function done() {
    setTimeout( function() {
        updates();
        done();
    }, 200);
}

function updates() {
    $.getJSON("fetch.php", function(data) {
        $("ul").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function(){
            $("ul").append("<li>Item: "+this['item']+
               "</li><li>Price: "+this['price']+"<br />")

            $("ul").append("<div id='a'><input type='submit' 
                 style='position:relative;top:100px;'>" + "<br /></div>" )

        });

    });
}
```

Comment: So what problem are you having?

Comment: a JSFiddle or at least a more thorough explanation or a sample of the markup would be helpful

Comment: `I need to create a unique div and a unique name for each submit button` Why do you need a unique div and button.. There might be a better solution if you can explain your problem .. Also you are trying to append invalid `HTML` .. `ul` elements semantically should contain `li` as their only direct children..

Comment: @Sushanth-- Am creating a shopping cart... by fetching the data of the shopping cart from mysql database and output them as a list. 
So, I am adding with each item in list a submit button, actually I need two, one for buy and the other for remove.
So that I need the unique name for each button ...

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a unique suffix for the id using the current date time

```
function generateRandomSuffix() {
    return (new Date()).getMilliseconds().toString()
}
```

Then add it to your id

```
$("ul").append("<div id='a" + generateRandomSuffix() +"'><input type='submit' style='position:relative;top:100px;'>" + "<br /></div>" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a counter and with each iteration of the div id, append the counter value to the relevant element of the tag. Just make sure you increment the counter each time you use it for the last time needed. A quick pseudocode example:

```
$counter = 0;
$("ul").append("/<div id='a"+$counter+"'><input type='submit' id='submit"+($counter++)+" style...
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case it is better to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`,
and you can do something like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () { updates() }, 200);
    });

var curid = 0;
function updates() {
    $.getJSON("fetch.php", function (data) {
        var html = '<ul>';
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            html += "<li>Item: " + this['item'] + "</li><li>Price: " + this['price'] + "<br />";
            html += "<input type='submit' style='position:relative;top:100px;'>" + "<br />";
        });
        html +='</ul>';

        curid += 1;
        var box = document.createElement("div");
        box.id = "div" + curid;
        box.className = "myclass";
        document.body.appendChild(box);
        box.innerHTML(html);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var counter = 0;
function updates() {
    var $ul = $('ul');
    $.getJSON("fetch.php", function(data) {
        $ul.empty();
        $.each(data.result, function(){
            counter++;

            var $li = $('<li />');
            $li.append("<li>Item: "+this['item'] + '<br />');
            $li.append("Price: "+this['price'] + '<br />');

            $('<div />', {
                id: counter
            }).append('<input type="submit" style="position:relative;top:100px;"/>').a[appendTo($li)

            $ul.append($li)

        });

    });
}
```